# Why reading an array with more than index doesn't throw an error?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I work on web site with pre-existent javascript code.

I found out that in this code, it used to retrieve an array item in this way:

```
var value = myArray[0, 1];
```

The result is the second field of the array, but I can't understand the difference with a code like:

```
var value = myArray[1];
```

I have tried to change the number before comma but nothing change, it reads always the second item of the array.

Comment: It's the JavaScript comma operator. A series of expressions separated by commas evaluates all of them, but the overall value of the series is the value of the *last* expression. Thus, in `0, 1` there are two expressions, and the last one is `1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comma operator evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand. That's why you get 1.